# what is the probability that the device will operate for at least another three hours?

Tags: probability

The lifetime of a phone is $X$ with pdf $f_{X}(x)=\frac{18}{x^{3}}$ where $x>3$. If six hours have passed since the device was activated and it is still operating, what is the probability that it will operate for at least another three hours?

I'm trying to solve this question for some time. The first thing that came to my mind is that $X$ should has Exponential distribution but it's looks like it's not the case. It feels like I need to use $f_{X|X}(x|x)$ but what does it even mean? Never saw a formula for it. I know that $f_{X|Y}(x|y)=\frac{f_{X,Y}}{f_Y(x)(x,x)}$ so should it be $f_{X|X}(x|x)=\frac{f_{X,X}(x,x)}{f_X(x)}$? It also does not make sense because I can't calculate $f_{X,X}(x,x)$ as $X$ dependents to itself. How to solve it?

Also, as I remember, lifetime is usually memoryless. So shouldn't the answer just be:
$$
P(X>9|X>6)=P(X>9)=\int_9^{\infty}f_X(x)dx=\int_9^{\infty}\frac{18}{x^{3}}dx=\frac{1}{9}
$$
But how can I use it without actually proving it?

**EDIT**: Found out that the answer should be $\frac{36}{81}$. But why?

Comment: Check your understanding of the conditional probability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overthink it. You know $$\text{prob}(X \geq 9\ |\ X \geq 6) = \text{prob}(X \geq 9\ \text{and}\ X \geq 6) / \text{prob}(X \geq 6).$$ And you're spot on that $\text{prob}(X \geq 9\ \text{and}\ X \geq 6) = \text{prob}(X \geq 9)$.